# How does AngularJS's own website serve SEO-friendly pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, seo

You can see an example of the pre-rendered content that AngularJS.org serves to the Google bot and other scrapers at http://docs.angularjs.org/?_escaped_fragment_=/tutorial/step_09

I'm curious as to how this was implemented. It doesn't seem like they're using a headless browser to generate snapshots, but are instead rendering the markup server-side. But I can't seem to find how this is implemented on their site's Github repo: https://github.com/angular/angularjs.org

Comment: In AngularJS site, the key is in .htaccess.

Comment: I don't see anything having to do with ?_escaped_fragment_ in the .htaccess, though. Also, the response headers on the actual website say it's nginx...though, I realize nginx could just be serving as a proxy.

Comment: The example URL  http://docs.angularjs.org/?_escaped_fragment_=/tutorial/step_09 is not correct. This URL would be ok if the site was using #! but since it is using the pushState API, the good URL is http://docs.angularjs.orgtutorial/step_09/?_escaped_fragment_=

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [this article](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/serious-angular-seo.html) explaining how to enable pre-render for each server configuration.
Alternatively check [prerender.io](http://prerender.io/) that can do pre-rendering for you.

Answer (score 1):

We have tried different solutions (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22313776/162345) list). We decided to go with Seo4Ajax as our prerendering service.